# Thermodynamics and its equations

Tags: thermodynamics

If found an equation that confuses me a lot. In isochoric process 
$$ dU=C_v \, dT+(du/dv)_t\, dv \quad. $$
Where,

- $C$ ... specific heat capacity at constant volume.
- $T$ ... temp
- $U$ ... internal energy
- $u$ ... specific energy
- $(du/dv)_t$ ... change of energy per volume change
- $V$ ... volume

My confusion is between the two terms on the right side. While the first term of the right-hand-side should be at constant volume, the second term should be at constant temp. But if one is kept constant, the other side becomes zero.

- Are my thoughts correct, or are there any situations where both can be kept constant?

Comment: Tip: write equations between dollar symbols and use laTex notation. See the guide. Plus, you should divide your question in paragraphs  to make reading easier.

Comment: Have you learned about partial derivatives in math yet?

Comment: Yes i have read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be a bit confused about the purpose of the equation. It is to express a small change in a fluid's internal energy in terms of changes in volume and temperature.

We're dealing with a gas (or liquid) in which the internal energy, *U*, can be regarded as a function of two other variables, in this case volume and temperature. Then (since you know about partial derivatives), $$dU={\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right)}_{V}dT + {\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)}_{T}dV$$ But the heat capacity at constant volume is defined by$${\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right)}_{V}=C_V.$$ So $$dU=C_{V}\ dT + {\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)}_{T}dV$$Therefore for an isochoric process ($dV=0$) we have simply $$dU=C_{V}\ dT$$
I've written these equations for any chosen amount of substance. It's up to you to tailor them to *per unit mass* or *per mole* versions.